# Laravel validation on array of radio inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm developing a module that have multiple radio inputs and has numeric index,
I have 15 radio input groups and each group has 7 radio input members with the same index.

I want to check each input if empty.

[HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmz9i.jpg)

I have tried dynamic requests validation on laravel it failed to validate.

I tried to hard code the validation of 15 inputs = failed,
Then I tried to test it individually and adding next index on success and it only validates up to 12th item/index.

my valdation code

```
$rules = [];
foreach($this->request->get('ratingsd') as $key => $val)
{
   $rules["ratings[$val]"] = 'required';
}



<div class="card mb-3 bg-info">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush bg-light">
        @foreach($items as $index=>$group)
        <li class="list-inline">
            <h5 class="card-header text-white bg-info">
                {{$group->group_name}}
            </h5>
        </li>
        @foreach($group->items as $items=>$item)
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="font-weight-bold">
                {{ $item->number }} {{ $item->entry }}
            </span>
            <div class="float-md-right form-inline mt-2">
                @foreach($ratings as $rate_value=>$rate_text)
                    {!!Form::hidden("ratingsd[".$item->item_id."]", $item->item_id)!!}
                    {!!Form::radio("ratings[$item->item_id]", $rate_text, "$group->group_id*$item->item_id*$rate_value")->inline()!!}
                @endforeach
                {!!Form::textarea("remarks[".$item->item_id."]", '')->placeholder('Remarks')->inline()!!}
            </div>
        </li>
        @endforeach

                    @endforeach
        <li class="list-inline bg-info text-white">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Overall Remarks
            </h5>
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item p-1">
            {!!Form::textarea("overall_remark", '')->placeholder('Remarks')->inline()!!}
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item text-center p-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I expect to validate properly each "ratings" radio inputs

Comment: what name attribute have you given to the inputs?

Comment: anyway it also failed validating on "remarks" input

Comment: @CodeBoyCode its "ratings" the exact naming is  ratings[54] to ratings[68]

Comment: {!!Form::hidden("ratingsd[".$item->item_id."]", $item->item_id)!!} - is that a spelling mistake? ratingsd?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode ratingsd is a hidden element holding the keys of ratings element, I did that because option input type is not submitted if there is no selected item on particular index array

Comment: @CodeBoyCode radio input type I mean, not option